Buying small shareholders via reverse stock split and fiduciary duty
This question presents a case where a company bought out small shareholders via reverse stock split. Is seems the buyout price was pretty much the trading price at the time of announcement, and the small shareholders had no choice.
Normally, a buying offer is significantly above trading price, and from a 3rd party. This decision came from management, which has a fiduciary duty to (all?) shareholders. From my perspective, a significantly higher price should have been offered.
Is this buyout via reverse split at trade price not a breach of fiduciary duty? If not, how so?


Normally, a buying offer is significantly above trading price, and
from a 3rd party. This decision came from management, which has a
fiduciary duty to (all?) shareholders. From my perspective, a
significantly higher price should have been offered.
Is this buyout via reverse split at trade price not a breach of
fiduciary duty? If not, how so?

If the shareholders that control a majority of the votes want to do this type of maneuver, why would that be a breech of the the boards fiduciary duty?
I am assuming there is nothing in the current corporate governance documents that would block this type of transaction.
When the move to go private is done by a merger or an acqu9isition the board has to determine what is the fair value, and does this transaction achieve that level of value.  In a reverse split transaction to go private they are being given exactly what the shares are trading for.
While there are costs with the reverse stock split when the small shareholders are given cash; there are also costs involved when a merger or acquisition is used to go private. Those small shareholders will end up with cash. The merging companies have to determine if the price being paid is fair.

Usually there is a "control premium" that 3rd parties must pay to reach majority control. I find it odd that in this case there is none, although the remaining shareholders benefit from forcing going private on the small shareholders.
